# MediaTek MT7610U (RT2860) driver won't compile

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, usb, source-code

I just bought a USB wi-fi dongle using the MediaTek MT7610U (RT2860) chipset, and the drivers from their website:
http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/mt7610u-usb/
won't compile, with this error

```
ktweed@PC-BL100TA ~/Desktop/drivers $ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ktweed/Desktop/drivers/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ktweed/Desktop/drivers/tools'
/home/ktweed/Desktop/drivers/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7650u
chipset = mt7630u
chipset = mt7610u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/ktweed/Desktop/drivers/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-89-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/ktweed/Desktop/drivers/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/lib/modules/3.2.0-89-generic/build' 
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lib/modules/3.2.0-89-generic/build'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

I tried using files modified according to this site, with the same error:
http://earthwithsun.com/questions/738096/how-to-install-mediatek-mt7610u-rt2860-driver

LSUSB output

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:13fd Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

The Ralink one is the USB Wifi.

ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0d:5e:ed:d3:4e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:5538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:609333 (609.3 KB)  TX bytes:609333 (609.3 KB)
```

I'm running linux mint 13 XFCE 32-bit. I've tried everything, and nothing works. If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks!

Edit:
The CD that came with the USB Wifi has drivers for a realtek 8188CUS, and those don't work either. Does this help?

Comment: I also tried this on a Raspberry Pi 2 and a Lenovo Thinkpad W700 with Ubuntu 15.04. Neither worked.

Comment: Try this, works perfectly fine for me for MT7610U (LTERIVER, JOIOT AC600)
https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From lsusb output, 148f:7601, it should be a MT7601U chip not MT7610U. Please node, Mediatek official site seem swap the link between them, but I'm not very sure about this.

I believe some guys have made good progress on MT7601U, refer to https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u

You can see, that driver are committed to 4.2 kernel.

I have a MT7610U usb adapter, I'm very sure I cannot use MT7601U driver, after I've tried so many drivers. My adapter lsusb output:

> Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried googling that, and I found this:https://code.launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/mt7601 It worked, although I did switch to Lubuntu 15.04 for it to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm glad to see you've found the solution by yourself.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot on kernel 4.19 or above. This version should work smoothly because there is native support for mt7610u.